# Translate en entity type created with eck - argument in menu

Tags: routes, i18n-l10n, entities

I am trying to use an entity type created with [Entity Construction Kit](http://drupal.org/project/eck) together with [Entity translation](http://drupal.org/project/entity_translation). There are some issues, i am trying to resolve them ...

- the [fatal error](http://drupal.org/node/1370900) on entity view was easy
- but the [other one](http://drupal.org/node/1440476) is a little more tricky :

Eck constructs its menus with both the entity type and the bundle type in the path, so the proper menu entries for translation aren't created.

I tried a workaround adding this into my feature (currently i only have 1 bundle anyway) :

```
function my_feature_translation_info($types = NULL) {
  $info['mytype'] = array(
    'translation' => array(
      'entity_translation' => array(
        'base path' => 'mytype/mytype/%',
      ),
    ),
  );
```

It helped to show the translation tab, but the tab didn't work, because eck doesn't use the "magic placeholder processing" and the entity_translation callback is supposing that the entity be loaded by that.

Another attempted workaround is to create a menu path (the common "node/%node" pattern according to translation code comments) as it is supposed in entity_translation_entity_info_alter, with a loader

```
  $items['mytype/%mytype'] = array(
    'title' => '',
    'description' => '',
    'page callback' => 'eck__entity__view',
    'page arguments' => array('mytype','mytype',2),
    'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM,
    'file' => '../../contrib/eck/eck.entity.inc'
  );

function mytype_load($id) {
  $ea = entity_load('panelco', array($id));
  return $ea[$id];
}
```

This is almost good : the translate path works ! My newly defined view path (mytype/1) doesn't , failing with

> Undefined index: in eck__entity__view()

, which is currently beyond my understanding.